# How to completely remove mobile browser long-press vibration?

Tags: javascript, web, mobile

I'm trying to completely remove the vibration that occurs on a long press of an element in a mobile browser.

Specifically, I have an image that I'm adding my own long-press functionality to, but the subtle short-vibrate that happens by default is interfering and I need to disable it.

I've successfully stopped the usual context menu from appearing by overriding it as follows:

```
window.oncontextmenu = function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  return false;
};
```

I've also added CSS to stop highlights and text selection etc - but I haven't been able to figure out what's causing the default vibrate after a few hundred ms.

Is there another lifecycle event that's popped on a long-press in a mobile browser, in or around oncontextmenu?

Full plunker Example here, long-press on the image from a mobile browser (I'm using chrome on Android) to see what I mean: https://plnkr.co/edit/y1KVPltTzEhQeMWGMa1F?p=preview

Comment: In Firefox is even worse. Instead of vibrating, Firefox for Android cancels the touch point (fires `touchcancel`)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disable the text selection when its clicked on.

```
document.querySelector("#your_target").addEventListener("touchstart", (e) =>
{
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.style.userSelect = "none";
});

document.querySelector("#your_target").addEventListener("touchend", (e) =>
{
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.style.userSelect = "default";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `touch-action: none;` in CSS. Then you might be able to handle an interaction event to do what you want.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action

Answer (score 0):

*NOT* setting `window.oncontextmenu` on Android removed the long press vibration for me.

You still also need to set `user-select: none`.